# Cosuming SOAP service from node.js

Tags: node.js, soap

I am consuming SOAP service , my code is :

function myfunction() {

```
var result = 0;
 soap.createClient('http://ipaddress/servicename?wsdl', function(err,    client) {

       client.myServiceFunction(parameters, function (err, result, body) {

        parseString(body, function (err, response) {

            console.log(response);
        })
    })
}
```

)
}

But I am getting "getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND"  error and its working in postman.

Thank you.

Comment: Remove 'http://' Can you try 'ipaddress/servicename?wsdl' instead?

Comment: have tried that also,but not working.